# Adding fields to block

Tags: blocks, display-suite

I am using Display Suite and have followed the instructions below exactly:

- Enable the sub module Display Suite Extras at Administration >
  Modules (admin/modules) Go to Administration > Structure > Display
  Suite and click the secondary tab "Extras"
  (admin/structure/ds/extras)
- Select the vertical tab "Others"
- Check "Region to block"
- Click "Save configuration"
- Go to Administration > Structure > Display Suite
  (admin/structure/ds/layout) and choose "manage display” for the
  desired content type (e.g., "Article").
- Select a custom view mode (e.g., "Compact teaser")
- Ensure a layout is selected in the vertical tab "Layout for … in ..."
- Click "Save"
- Choose the vertical tab "Block regions"
- Enter a name for the region that will be rendered as a block
- Click "Save"
- The region is now available in the manage display screen and you can
  assign fields to it.
- The block is now available via Administration > Structure > Blocks (admin/structure/ds/blocks) where you can enable it.

I am able to enable the block, however, I can only enter the title and none of the fields I placed in the new region I created can be configured. Has anyone else tried this approach to adding fields to a block?

Comment: did you follow this https://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/36472

Comment: my instructions are exactly as stated in your link.

Comment: did you enable the fields on manage display for your display

Comment: yes i already did so.

Comment: have you considered Drupal Beans? drupal.org/project/bean